# @recogito/annotorious : show annotation below rectangle always

Tags: javascript, html, css, annotations, customization

I am using https://github.com/recogito/annotorious to draw annotation over image.
[image]
I want to show annotation text always.
[image]

Below is I am trying code.

```
const anno = Annotorious.init({
    image: 'test',
    locale: 'auto',
    widgets: [{ widget: 'COMMENT' }],
});
         
// This is I am trying, but, this is not that function, Is there other option or plugin ?
anno.setVisible(true);
```

Is there other option or plugin ?

Comment: If you search gitter https://gitter.im/recogito/annotorious for "position" you will find some threads on the topic of where the pop up positions relative to the image. The short is that it is draggable based on feedback. For showing the entered annotation I think you would want to do that outside of the widget with your own JS, or write your own custom widget that extends the base widget with this functionality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the text to display always, you should take a look at the Shape Labels plugin:
https://github.com/recogito/recogito-client-plugins/tree/main/packages/annotorious-shape-labels

It will display three first tag in the annotation, but you can tweak the code easily to show e.g. the comment instead.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, and, that is working well

Answer (score 0):

Try changing Drawing Tool

```
var toolName = 'polygon';  // 'rect' or 'polygon'
anno.setDrawingTool(toolName);
```